# Phalcon: Migration command not working

Tags: php, migration, phalcon

I am runing following command

```
./phalcon gen-migration --help
```

which results error:

```
Phalcon DevTools (2.0.13)
Error: gen-migration is not a recognized command.
```

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/issues/46

Comment: @randy Make it as a proper answer by giving solution here rather than a link and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

I've the same error with Phalcon DevTools (3.4.0)
You can explore tool commands with

```
phalcon help
```

And then if you want to see migration commands you just type

```
phalcon migration
```

Command for your case should be the following

```
phalcon migration run
```

Be sure you have php database drive installed!